# WKWebView load Function in which Thread

Tags: wkwebview

I am developing an App with an iOS Deployment target 15.6.
The App uses WKWebview for obtaining url information such as html. When I run a webView.load(url) function in the main thread it works but issues a warning "This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness."
Although the function should not be used in a background thread I tried it but of course I got an error message "WKWebView.load(_:) must be used from main thread only".
How can I use the load function correctly so that I receive no warnings?